# How to create a user-impaired accessible website: surfing without a mouse?

Tags: web, accessibility, wai-aria, keyboard-navigation

I have created a webpage using Backbone.js and Marionette.js that mostly consists of a bootstrap accordion view that displays a list of items when the accordion header is clicked. Each item can also be clicked, which will show a hidden div of detailed information that pertains to that particular item.

I would like to make this site accessible to people who might not be using a mouse (Maybe they're visually impaired and using a screen reader? Maybe they just don't like clicking things? Either way.) I'm thinking that this would mean being able to press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to get to the accordion, pressing <kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open the accordion, Tabbing down (or down arrow key?) through the list items, and then using <kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> to show the selected item's hidden `div`.

I'm finding it difficult to find information on how to add a feature like this, since searches like "How to make an accessible website that can be used without a mouse" mostly turns up blogs on what a developer *should* do to add accessibility to a page, and not much on *how* to do it.

Currently, the page doesn't really respond to any keyboard buttons. Any tips or resources you could share would be extremely appreciated. I've been fiddling with ARIA role tags, but I'm either not doing it right or it's not the answer here.

Comment: Buttons, form fields and links are meant to be focused as well as clicked: do you use them? Otherwise SO isn't a site suitable for such a broad question; only for precise questions with some code.

Comment: This is a very nice implementation of accessibility (and semantic markup) within an accordion: http://www.sitepoint.com/introducing-accessible-accordion-widget/

Comment: That's perfect thanks. I think I have everything I need now.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use tabindex

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.tabIndex

Screen readers automatically read whatever element is the activeElement